# What is the difference between Java Collections' two toArray() functions?

Tags: java, collections

Located [here.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collection.java#Collection.toArray%28%29) Reading through these docs, it's not clear to me the reason that this distinction is made. The difference clearly is that the first method returns an Object array, and it looks like the second returns a Generic array. Could you please explain how these would be implemented differently and what the distinction is between them?

Comment: The first example makes no sense at all. `String` is not a `List[]`, so that won't even compile.

Comment: One of them takes a generic array as parameter `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a);` . They are different.

Comment: `The difference clearly is that the first method returns an Object array, and it looks like the second returns a Generic array.` Note that the main difference is not the return type, but the parameters of the methods. [In earlier Java versions](http://www.cs.mun.ca/~michael/java/jdk1.2-docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray()), both returned `Object[]` - that has simply been changed to a generic type to avoid unnecessary casts once generics were available.

Comment: @AndreasFester Well, there is obviuosly a difference in the parameters list. But the main difference between the two methods (also in ancient times) is the returned _runtime type_. Although the method signature of the second method might have been `Object[] toArray(...)`, it easily can return a `String[]`, for example. Whereas the first method only returns an `Object[]` (and no subtype). In one case, a cast can be done. In the other case, you have to live with the return type.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Definitely true, that is the difference in *runtime* behaviour (and you properly explained it in your answer). Just wanted to outline to OP that the *obvious* difference is the parameters, not the return types (but maybe OP is already talking about the *runtime* return type, that is not clear from the question)

Comment: @AndreasFester Yes, you are right. This is somewhat unclear in the question. But OP might now have some insight in this topic by simply reading the comments. :-)

Comment: Your comments are helping me understand it so thank you! However, I don't understand why the toArray() needs to return an Object[]. Is a, for example, List<String> not able to find that it contains Strings? If so, couldn't someList.toArray() return a String[] where someList is a List<String>?

Also, my examples made no sense... sorry for that.

Comment: @WarSame As I explained in my answer, generic types are erased at runtime. So, yes, a `Collection<Whatever>` is not able to determine its own generic type. This differs from arrays that indeed know their base type, even at runtime.

Comment: Ah, that is the key element I was missing. I assumed they could find it out like most other things can. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method

```
<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
```

already gets an array as a parameter and thus is able to return an array *with the same base type*.

The method

```
Object[] toArray()
```

does not know the base type (remind: generic types are erased at runtime), so it can only return an object array.

Simply said: For a `Collection<String>` you will get a `String[]` when calling the first method, and you will get an `Object[]` when calling the second method. And these are different types.

Just a note: This is other as with collections. As generic types are erased at runtime, a `List<String>` and a `List<Object>` are the same `List` type at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

These methods returns the elements of a collection inside an array.

There are two differences between the 2 methods

1. The first one is not generic (meaning you'll need casting) while the second one is generic
2. The first one will instantiate a new array, while in the second one you may provide yourself the array that will be used. Its size needs to be equals or greater than the number of elements in the collection (or the method will also have to instantiate an array), but you can provide a bigger one if you plan to add more element to it.

And for your code, it won't compile

```
List<String> myCollection = new ArrayList<>();
nyCollection.add("example");
Object[] array1 = myCollection.toArray();

// a new array will be created by the toArray method
String[] array2 = myCollection.toArray(new String[0]);

// the provided array will be used
String[] array3 = myCollection.toArray(new String[2]);
```

Comment: Why not say `new String[0]`?

Comment: Your point 1 is wrong. You cannot cast a returned `Object[]` to a - let's say - `String[]`, when having a `Collection<String>`. And this is the reason for the existence of the generic method.

Comment: it did not say that ;) You'll need casting in a for loop : for(Object o : array1) {String e = (String)o;...}

Comment: Then make clear your meaning, because - otherwise - you exactly said that. ;-)

Comment: And additionally, your second point is also wrong (and is contradicted by your own example)! You can pass a zero-sized array to the method. An new array with the correct base type will be created then.